# using antlr parse message, how to resolve ambiguous literal

Tags: antlr

I am a newbie with ANTLR and try to parse a [World Meteorological Organization (WMO) messages](https://www.weather.gov/tg/head) using ANTLR. A message like this: “AVB 12 CVD A12”。This is my grammar:

```
grammar a;

rule : aaa bbb? ccc ddd;
aaa: char char char ;
bbb: Digit Digit ;
ccc: ('+'|'-')? char 'V' char;
ddd: 'A' Digit Digit;
char : 'A'|'V'| Char;

Char: [A-Z];
Digit: [0-9];
WS: [ \t\n\r=] ->skip;
```

and it works! But the lexer tokenizes just a single char from the input and I don't know another method. Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Can you show us how your input looks like? I have edited your question, hoping that I better expressed your intention. If that was wrong please let me know.

Comment: @MikeLischke from an earlier SO question, Lao mentioned they're WMO messages. I edited this question accordingly.

Comment: I see, ok, but this grammar works fine with the given input. @laowang can you explain what's not working for you? Maybe different input?

Comment: Mike, This grammar is ok, I just want to know if has another approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would clean things up a bit to recognize most of these as tokens.

I don't know the semantics of what you're trying to parse, so I don't know what would be appropriate names.  (I'll use L# an p# for Lexer and Parser rules accordingly.

```
grammar a;

rule : L1 L2? L3 L4;

fragment CHAR: [A-Z];
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];

L3: ('+'|'-')? CHAR 'V' CHAR; // place before L1 for to take precedence for "*V*" chars 
L1: CHAR CHAR CHAR ;
L2: DIGIT DIGIT ;
L4: 'A' Digit Digit;

WS: [ \t\n\r=] ->skip;
```

Once you give the tokens meaningful names, the grammar (and the generated *Context classes will be easier to deal with than if you treat each character as a token.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but your grammar can not work to parse "AVB 12 CVD A12" . AVB is tokenized to L3, it's expected to L1.

Comment: Ah, I see.  The interpretation of the three letter sequences seems to be context sensitive, and would need to be handled by parser rules, as their evaluation is controlled by the parent rule.  Lexer rules won't be able to distinguish "AVB" in the first slot of you `rule`, vs "AVB" in the third slot in your `rule`.

Comment: This leaves you in the "scanner less parser" territory, where the recursive descent parser rules can control everything.  tokenizing single characters gives you pretty much the same effect in ANTLR.  I don't see any substantial changes I'd recommend.

Comment: the "char: 'A' | 'V' | Char;" rule threw me for a second.  You *might* want to change the `Char` rule to `[B-UW-Z]` to make it clear that "A" and "V" won't ever match (but that's hardly substantive.)